# Heroku slow image loading

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

Hi I deployed my react+nodejs project to heroku.
My website runs properly except image loading, I am using 1-2MB images.
In my localhost server it works perfectly, why is heroku so slow?
Is it the bad heroku servers? or my images is too heavy? and how do I fix it except resizing images wight?

[My heroku website](https://myburgermarket.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-2 MB is huge, you need to reduce the size to at least 200KB and even less for small screens